# c# json force patch

Tags: c#, .net, json, json-patch

Let's say there an empty is JSON object:

```
String obj1 = "{}";
```

Is there a way to patch update it and force creation of missing path using C#?
So after patch like this:

```
{ "op": "add", "path": "/a/b", "value": "foo" },
```

the result will be: `{ a: { b: "foo" } }`

Comment: I doubt that there exists any special way to do it. You will probably have to parse both jsons into objects and apply the transformations manually.

Comment: well, there are libs like JsonDiffPatch but it throws an exception when part of the path is missing.

Comment: Perhaps there are some settings that make JsonDiffPatch to create missing nodes?

Comment: I can't find anything like that

Comment: Just to clarify. You have two strings that represent JSON in C#, and you want to merge these JSON objects and then deserialize resulted string to C# object?

Answer (score 0):

not sure what is your problem exactly, if I'm wrong my bad, you can create those custom json objects in C# using System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject or using IDictionary, or both as in my example (case I'm lazy),
as in the comments being said this is more like a parse, not a transform:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ExpandoObject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string stringObj;
            stringObj = "{\"op\": \"add\", \"path\": \"/a/b\", \"value\": \"foo\"}";
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GetObjectPatchResult(stringObj)));
            stringObj = "{\"op\": \"add\", \"path\": \"/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j\", \"value\": \"foo\"}";
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GetObjectPatchResult(stringObj)));
        }

        private static object GetObjectPatchResult(string param)
        {
            dynamic expando = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
            var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)expando;
            var parchObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PatchObject>(param);
            var level = result;
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var path in parchObject.Path.Split('/'))
            {
                i++;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path)) continue;
                dynamic pathExpando = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
                level[path] = (IDictionary<string, object>)pathExpando;
                if (i < parchObject.Path.Split('/').Count())
                {
                    level = (IDictionary<string, object>)level[path];
                }
                else
                {
                    level[path] = parchObject.Value;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public class PatchObject
    {
        public string Op { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

result:

> {"a":{"b":"foo"}}
>
> {"a":{"b":{"c":{"d":{"e":{"f":{"g":{"h":{"i":{"j":"foo"}}}}}}}}}}
>
> Press any key to continue . . .